# Android access view binding val outside onCreate activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I have an activity that has a button. On the button click I want to update text in text view.
I want to use `ViewBinding` instead of the normal `findViewById`

This is how I created the val binding

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.btnRoll.setOnClickListener {
        rollDice()
    }
}
```

Now in `rollDice` I want to update the text view but I'm not able to access binding which make sense because its scope is limited to `onCreate()` , so what is the best practice for this?

```
  private fun rollDice() {
       val random = Random().nextInt(6) + 1
       binding.txt_random.setText("random")
    }
```

Comment: you can declare it outside on create . There is no issue in that.

Comment: Add a property `lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding`, and remove the `val` prefix from your `binding = ` line.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks , I will accept it if you post it as reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options.

### 1. Store in a property

Since the inflated content of Activity is fully bound to it's lifecycle, it's safe to keep the reference as a property

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.btnRoll.setOnClickListener {
      rollDice()
    }
  }

  private fun rollDice() {
    val random = Random().nextInt(6) + 1
    binding.txt_random.setText("random")
  }
}
```

### 2. Pass the binding to the methods

That's what I usually do, it avoids creating a property where it's not really a necessity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater);
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.btnRoll.setOnClickListener {
      rollDice(binding)
    }
  }

  private fun rollDice(binding: ActivityMainBinding) {
    val random = Random().nextInt(6) + 1
    binding.txt_random.setText("random")
  }
}
```

Both options are valid ways to make the binding visible to Activities methods.

Comment: Also if you're doing a fragment, you can use the alternate constructor (the one that takes a layout ID) and instead of implementing ``onCreateView`` you can do ``onViewCreated`` instead, and call ``binding = CoolFragmentBinding.bind(view)`` instead of inflating the layout yourself. There's a similar constructor for ``AppCompatActivity`` but geting its inflated view is awkward, so inflating it via the binding and passing the root to ``setContentView`` is probably cleanest

Comment: @cactustictacs that's how I also do it for fragments, but keep in mind that a fragment can actually outlive it's view, and keeping a property reference to the binding requires clearing it once `onDestroyView()` is called, otherwise the reference may leak.

Answer (score 4):

As the question has accepted answer and it is already addressed but here is my approach to the viewBinding

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      private val binding by lazy{
         ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       }  
    
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    
        binding.btnRoll.setOnClickListener {
          rollDice()
        }
      }
    
      private fun rollDice() {
        val random = Random().nextInt(6) + 1
        binding.txt_random.setText("random")
      }
    }
```

I go with lazy initialization of binding so that way it is only intitialized if it is required.
More you can read about lazy initialization here
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/lazy-initialization

Answer (score 0):

Store the binding in an instance variable on the Activity. Then you have access to it from all the methods in the Activity.

Comment: Correct terminology is property. In Kotlin, variables and (member) properties behave differently, and variables are only available within functions.